# Time complexity of c++ math library pow() function?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I wanted to know what is the worst case time-complexity of the pow() function that's built in c++?

Comment: Complexity is a measure of growth when a function (e.g., sorting) is applied to a larger number of inputs. Given that `pow` always has exactly the same number of inputs, complexity (at least as the term is normally used) simply doesn't apply. You can apply complexity measures based on the size of a single input, but that doesn't generally apply to something like `pow` in the standard library that takes only a fixed-size input. It could/would apply to computing powers when dealing with arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Won't number of bits in the exponent count? It isn't entirely unreasonable to consider complexity of `f(x)` in terms of `x` and to assume that it is unbounded (the number of inputs is also bounded by practical limits).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: There is sometimes measurable variation between values withing a type like double, but at least when I've measured, the relationship wasn't to something as simple as the magnitudes of the numbers. IOW, yes there may be an `O(f(x))`, but it's not entirely clear what `x` is, not to mention what `f(x)` is. I say "may be", because it's also unclear that the concept of `x` approaching infinity applies in this case. It's ultimately more about precision than the magnitudes of the numbers though.

Comment: Not a dup, but related: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638473/4594973](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4638473/4594973).

Answer (score 20):

That depends on the underlying architecture. On the most common desktop architecture, x86, this is a constant time operation.

See this question for more details on how it could be implemented on x86: [How to: pow(real, real) in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86)

Answer (score 2):

Here is [one implementation](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c), take a look. To be sure, it is a rather complex piece of code, with some 19 special cases. The time complexity does not appear to be dependent on the values passed in.

Here is a short description of the method used to compute `pow(x,y)`:

> ```
> Method:  Let `x =  2 * (1+f)`
> ```
>
> - Compute and return `log2(x)` in two pieces:
>       `log2(x) = w1 + w2`,
>      where `w1` has `53-24 = 29` bit trailing zeros.
> - Perform `y*log2(x) = n+y'` by simulating muti-precision 
>      arithmetic, where `|y'|<=0.5`.
> - Return `x**y = 2**n*exp(y'*log2)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what system/architecture you're on, so we are left guessing.

However, **if you're not looking for specifics and just want to browse the code** of a freely available implementation **See** http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/, specifically http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/w_pow.c

See this question's answer for more background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285277/25882