# How to use scientific notation with variable in C++?

Tags: c++, notation

I wanna know if it is possible to use the scientific notation with variables?

For example:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int x = 1en;
```

instead of

```
int x = 1e8
```

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: I know that, but "pow" takes O(logn) and I wanted to avoid using it here.

Comment: What makes you think that *"pow" takes O(logn)* ?

Comment: Write your own power function, as per requirement

Comment: What makes you think that `1eN` would perform better than `pow(1,N)`?

Comment: you mean that it takes less than O(logn)?

Comment: I mean, since both would be evaluated at runtime, they would theoretically perform exactly the same. It doesn't matter what the algorithm is.

Comment: pow is imlemented using very little machine instructions on x86. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86

Comment: I thought it uses something like "shifting the digits" for scientific notation.
But as you give me negatives for such question which wasn't asked by another person here, and it is not trivial, I will try not to ask questions here, anymore.
Why are you so nervous and unhappy against beginner's questions?!

Comment: "shifting the digits" can only be used if the exponent is 2 (or 4,8,16,etc.) since numbers are represented binary. Then it would be `1<<n`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Scientific notation is only for constant values. Those values are determined at compile time, while the value you want to get is determined at runtime.

You'll have to use something like `int result = pow(10,n)`. Keep in mind that [`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) returns double values.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can do is define a macro in the following way:

You cannot avoid using pow since n is evaluated at run time. This just like C works.

`#define e(n) *pow(10,n)`

And you use it:

`int n; cin >> n; int x = 1 e(n);`

Comment: @tenfour I tend to agree that he shouldn't use it. How ever this is still the closest he will get