# calculate power of real numbers in masm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x87

I am new in masm I don't know how to manage floating numbers. I am trying to find a exponent value e^x in masm Assembly. where x is floating number.
For example e^2.3

Comment: Others have asked [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86) [questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.asm.x86/ErWdaSH_3tQ).