# Computing powers in x87 floating point

Tags: math, assembly, floating-point, x87

Is there any way to compute powers of floating point numbers purely in x86/x87 assembly? I'm not talking about computing integral powers of floating point numbers, but something like x^y where both x **and** y are floating point numbers.

I have a solution for integral powers (NASM syntax):

```
compute_integral_powers:
    fldl [esp+4]              ;load base twice
    fld  st0
    movl ecx, [esp+12]        ;load exponent
.loop:
    decl ecx                  ;decrement exponent
    cmpl ecx, 0               ;are we done yet?
    jz   .done
    fmul st1                  ;multiply by original base
    jmp  .loop                ;keep going
.done:
    fstp st1                  ;store st0 in st1 and pop (for return value)
    ret
```

Is there something similar to compute powers using floating point exponents, using **only** x86/x87 assembly instructions?

Comment: If you compile a C implementation of the standard function `pow` to assembly then you'll have a floating-point implementation using only x86/x87 assembly instructions. Starting from a typical implementation with argument reduction followed by polynomial approximation, you can expect a couple hundred instructions for each (less if we are talking of a function for a precision narrower than the maximum available to the FPU).

Comment: Unless you are looking for the last drop of performance there is no reason to write this function in assembly. If `call pow` is an acceptable implementation with x86/87 instructions, you should definitely use that.

Comment: If you only care about x87 (and not about the SSE instructions), then look into the FYL2X and F2XM1 x87 instructions.

Comment: See also this related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4638502/270986

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86

Comment: @PascalCuoq - I'm writing this for a runtime library, and thus have no access to `call pow`.