# how does python calculate square roots?

Tags: python, number-theory

I noticed that square roots are pretty fast in python.

```
import time
a = time.time()
print((1234567891011121314151617181920**8)**0.5)
d = time.time()-a
print(d)
```

output:

```
2.32305723559e+120
0.0150001049042
```

That's a 200+ digit number in under 0.1 second!

So what's the algorithm behind all this?

Comment: Note: The `123...1920**8` is computed as a bigint, and then it is converted to floating-point double for the square root operation. Hence, the square root operates on a 64-bit FP number, not a "200-digit" fully accurate integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPython is just calling the C intrinsic `pow` in this case, letting the compiler do whatever it wants with it. [How to: pow(real, real) in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86) is one example of somewhere explaining a fast implementation of `pow` at a processor level.

Comment: @NickBastin, AFAIK it should call libm `sqrt` if you use `math.sqrt`, but in this case where OP did `some_float ** 0.5` we would follow the code path taking us to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L763

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how we end up with the `sqrt` call?

Comment: I did a `dis.dis()` on a func that did a direct sqrt from  `** 0.5` on our internal Python, but that appears to be something we optimized.  Typical CPython appears to assemble this as `BINARY_POWER`, so I take back my sqrt comment...