# pow with double base and double exponent

Tags: java, double

I am trying to write the following method in Java

```
double doublePow(double x, double pow);
```

Any pointers? Since both the base and the exponent can be double this is quite tricky for me. Any help would be appreciated.

examples:

```
x = doublePow (4, 0.5) ; // x = 2.0
x = doublePow (8, 0.333333333) ; // x = 1.9999999986137069
```

## do not want to use the library function

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Uh... `return Math.pow(x, pow);`?

Comment: Thanks! Don't want to use the library function.

Comment: Help how? You haven't said anything about what you're stuck on, or provided any code.

Comment: `return Math.exp(pow * Math.log(x));`? Unless you use some library function somewhere, you're going to have to implement some real ballaching code (which is why the libraries exist).

Comment: @AndyTurner How would you even write it yourself?  Can you get direct access to the FPU from Java?  Even `Math.pow()` just delegates to a native implementation.

Comment: "How would you even write it yourself?" I'm not even going to try. But you could do it using series expansions, for example.

Comment: I would give up pretty quickly; this is not a practical method to implement by yourself if you don't have at least a week to devote to it and nothing else.

Comment: Oh Yes! This is possible. Though, I am trying to do it without using any built in function/log/exp etc. But no luck yet..

Comment: not using standard math libs will bring you to use numeric aproximations by implementing Taylor series or similar alg. such a waste of computational resources....

Comment: @LouisWasserman I have to agree to what you said!

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638473/how-to-powreal-real-in-x86

Comment: Doing this without any library functions would be horrific. I hate to think of the potential loss of precision you would get without having to represent everything as Strings as well.

Comment: Well, [here](http://repo.or.cz/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c) is a raw C implementation.  Good luck.