# How to optimize a method that transforms a byte[] to a 4d tensor (or array)?

Tags: c#, optimization

I am working on a program that removes a user's background in real-time using a webcam.

To do the background subtraction, I am using an ML model. The input of this model is a 4D tensor in the shape BCHW (batch, channel, height, width), where the RGB values range between 0 and 1. I am only using one image at the same time, so batch = 1, and it effectively makes it a 3D tensor.

So, I have to write some code to transform a byte array, the input image from the webcam, to the tensor.

Say you have an `byte[]` like this: `RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB RGB`,

then the code should transform it to: `RRRRRRRRR GGGGGGGGG BBBBBBBBB`.

To do this I have come up with the following method:

```
public Tensor<float> ImageToTensor(byte[] pixels, int height, int width)
{
    var tensorSize = 1 * 3 * height * width;

    float[] data = new float[tensorSize];

    var channelSize = width * height;
    var redChannel = 0;
    var greenChannel = channelSize;
    var blueChannel = (channelSize * 2);

    Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
    {
        int rowStart = y * width * 3;
        int rowWidth = width * 3;

        var row = new Span<byte>(pixels, rowStart, rowWidth);

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i += 3)
        {
            byte red = row[i];
            byte green = row[i + 1];
            byte blue = row[i + 2];

            var index = i / 3 + y * width;

            data[redChannel + index] = red / 255f;
            data[greenChannel + index] = green / 255f;
            data[blueChannel + index] = blue / 255f;
        }
    });

    Memory<float> memory = new Memory<float>(data);

    return new DenseTensor<float>(memory, new[] { 1, 3, height, width });
}
```

I have benchmarked this with an 1920 x 1080 image using Benchmarkdotnet, and it takes about 5 ms.

While this is not a lot, the ML model takes about 8 ms, and I also have a post-processing step.

The goal is to run the video stream at 60 FPS. This means the whole process can only take 16.6ms. Since the ML model takes 8ms, I only have about 8 to 9 ms left for the pre-processing and post-processing steps.

The post and pre-processing steps are roughly the same, but the post-processing step is a bit more complex and takes about double the time. So, I am currently at `5ms + 8ms + 10ms = 23ms`.

That's 6 - 7ms too much.

So, my question is, how do I optimize the code above?
I have already tried multiple things, but nothing really seems to improve it by a lot.

### Improved code:

```
public Tensor<float> ImageToTensor(byte[] pixels, int height, int width)
{
    var tensorSize = 1 * 3 * height * width;

    float[] data = new float[tensorSize];

    var channelSize = width * height;
    var redChannel = 0;
    var greenChannel = channelSize;
    var blueChannel = (channelSize * 2);

    int floatSlots = Vector<float>.Count;

    Parallel.For(0, height, y =>
    {
        int rowStart = y * width * 3;
        int rowWidth = width * 3;

        var row = new Span<byte>(pixels, rowStart, rowWidth);

        int numOfVectors = row.Length / (floatSlots * 3);
        int ceiling = numOfVectors * (floatSlots * 3);

        var reds = new float[floatSlots];
        var greens = new float[floatSlots];
        var blues = new float[floatSlots];

        for (int i = 0; i < ceiling; i += (floatSlots * 3))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (3 * floatSlots); j += 3)
            {
                reds[j / 3] = row[j] / 255f;
                greens[j / 3] = row[j + 1] / 255f;
                blues[j / 3] = row[j + 2] / 255f;
            }

            var vecRed = new Vector<float>(reds);
            var vecGreen = new Vector<float>(greens);
            var vecBlue = new Vector<float>(blues);

            vecRed.CopyTo(data, i + redChannel);
            vecGreen.CopyTo(data, i + greenChannel);
            vecBlue.CopyTo(data, i + blueChannel);
        }

        for (int i = ceiling; i < row.Length; i += 3)
        {
            byte red = row[i];
            byte green = row[i + 1];
            byte blue = row[i + 2];

            var index = i / 3 + y * width;

            data[redChannel + index] = red / 255f;
            data[greenChannel + index] = green / 255f;
            data[blueChannel + index] = blue / 255f;
        }
    });

    Memory<float> memory = new Memory<float>(data);

    return new DenseTensor<float>(memory, new[] { 1, 3, height, width });
}
```

I have improved my code by using SIMD Vectors and this made the code 20% faster. It went from 5ms to 4ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fairly good, so I would not expect any miracles of performance, but there are a few things you could try.

Instead of incrementing `i` by 3, I would suggest incrementing by one and multiplying by 3 inside the method, that would let you get rid of the divide, and multiplication is a [lot faster than division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505827/what-are-the-relative-cycle-times-for-the-6-basic-arithmetic-operations).

You could also consider [SIMD intrinstics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/), that might help quite a bit, but I have no idea how you should write it. You might also consider looking for optimized implementations, like [Intel performance Primitives](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-2-image-processing/image-data-exchange-and-initialization-functions/copy-1.html) or [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a). These should hopefully already be highly optimized, but might require a [.Net wrapper](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or pInvoke calls. Even if you do not want to use a third party solution, it might be worth testing to get an idea of the upper bound of the performance.

You might also consider using c++ instead. While most .net code benefit little from a straight c++ port in my experience, the c++ compiler has a wider range of optimization available that *might* help for tight loops like this.

If nothing else works you might consider just throwing hardware at the problem. I.e. more and faster cores. This might be a cheaper then spending lots of time on optimization, at least if this is a specialized implementation not intended for mass-market.

Comment: In regards to incrementing `i` by 1 instead of 3, it really doesn't matter, JIT is smart enough to eliminate the division entirely. In fact, the only real division that the resulting assembly calls is `divss` for the float division, which could be avoided by multiplying by `1f / 255f` instead of dividing by `255f`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have added an improved version of my code that uses SIMD Vectors. This made it 20% faster. It now takes 4ms instead of 5ms. I will leave it at that for now unless someone else might have an idea on how to improve it even further